# React Native Icon dissapears on the right side of my View

Tags: react-native

```
return (
      <View>
        <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/pizza.png')} style={styles.background}
          imageStyle={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            borderRadius: 20,
            opacity: 0.4,
            flexDirection: 'row'
          }}>
          <Text style={styles.recipeTitle}>{favorite.name}</Text>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name='clock-outline' size={30} color='#277093' style={styles.clockIcon}></MaterialCommunityIcons>
          <Text style={styles.cookTime}>~ {favorite.cookTime}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.delete} onPress={deleteIcon}>
            <AntDesign name='delete' size={30} color='red' ></AntDesign>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    )
  }

delete: {
    left: 35
  }
```

Comment: you are missing some detail there. which icon are you referring to? and can you share a screenshot of how it should look like?

Comment: If i wrap it out of the touchableopacity it appears but i want it to get clicked and i mean the delete icon

Comment: i am assuming that you are placing the delete icon on the far right, so try removing the `left: 35` and add `justifyContent: flex-end`.

Comment: if i do this the icon isnt at the border there is like a right margin or something

Comment: Set `marginRight: 0`?

Comment: nah it not that simple i delete touchableopacity the icon appears and if i wrap it in it dissappears

Comment: I need to fix it an i need touchable opacity there